# How to get the value of div having active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, jquery-events

I am trying to get the value from my custom checkbox made by div (instead of input) to my js file But it is getting undefined .

My HTML

```
@foreach($categories as $id => $category)
<div class="radio-btn">
   <div class="square-radio square-radio--checked" data-value="{{ $id }}" 
           id="category{{$loop->index + 1}}">
        <div class="square-radio--content"></div>
   </div>
</div>
@endforeach
// The square-radio--checked class gets active when the checkbox is checked
```

My js file

```
$('.square-radio').click(function(){
    var bipin = [];
    $('.square-radio--checked').each(function(){
        bipin.push($(this).data("value"));
    });
    console.log(bipin);
});
```

But in this case bipin array is coming with undefined but if I log the `data-value` it gives me the correct `id` as I asked

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using and what browser are you using?

Comment: There is no problem in your code

Comment: There is no way that *that* code can make `console.log(bipin)` output `undefined`. There must be a problem elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Checked simplified version of your code and it is working. Probably issue is somewhere else: https://codepen.io/makvrukova/pen/YzyarvW?editors=1111

Comment: @Marta thanks yes it was right ! . But it prints out all the checkbox data-value not specific one I checked . I dont know why ? is it because I have used foreach if yes how to solve it ?

Comment: @FredShirley, it prints out all the values, because you go through all the `$('.square-radio--checked')` elements and add their value to an array. Here is a modified pen to output only the clicked item's value: https://codepen.io/makvrukova/pen/dyYmZGN?editors=1111

Comment: @Marta will it work if I used the same logic for multiple filter like I checked one and again I checked another so it has to filter according to two datas

Comment: @FredShirley, sounds like it should work, you will need to put into the function that you pass to `each()` the condition that you will filter against. Set a `data-checked` attribute for example when clicking so you can select all `$('.square-radio--checked')` that have the `data-checked` attribute to gather their value.